# Extract picasaweb album names

Tags: bash, screen-scraping

I'd just like to get the album names. Here's an example page:

http://picasaweb.google.com/sunnchoi

But when I wget it and grep for a title pattern, I get 100 results. I understand that I have to emulate clicking the 'Show More Albums' link. How do I do that (using bash utils/perl)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Picases Web Album API](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/overview.html).

They have examples in Python/Java and other languages. Here's [request a list of albums](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#ListAlbums) (this one using python).

Answer (score 0):

If you have xmlstarlet available, you can directly parse the corresponding RSS URL of the given website:

```
xmlstarlet sel --net -T -t -m '//item' -v 'title' -n \
'http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/sunnchoi?alt=rss&kind=album&hl=en_US&access=public' | 
nl
```